# XML play list for projekktor player

Tags: xml, projekktor

Friends,
I am using Projekktor web player for my project.So I want to load videos to this player from external XML playlist.my script is below.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    projekktor('#player_a', {
        poster: '/media/intro.jpg',
        title: 'Projekktor - Playlist',
        volume: 0.1,
        playerFlashMP4: 'swf/StrobeMediaPlayback/StrobeMediaPlayback.swf',
        playerFlashMP3: 'swf/StrobeMediaPlayback/StrobeMediaPlayback.swf',
        width: 768,
        height: 432,
        platforms: ['browser', 'android', 'ios', 'native', 'flash', 'vlc'],
        // platforms: ['browser', 'ios', 'android', 'flash', 'native'],
        playlist: [
            {
                0: {src: "media/Kashmir Main tu Kanyakumari.mp4", type: "video/mp4"}
            },
            {
                0: {src: "media/Dedunnai Adare.mp4", type: "video/mp4"}
            },
            {
                0: {src: "media/Heer Toh Badi Sad Hai.mp4", type: "video/mp4"}
            },
            {
                0: {src: "media/Dheere Dheere Se Meri Zindagi REMIX.mp4", type: "video/mp4"}
            },
            {
                0: {src: "media/Matargashti.mp4", type: "video/mp4"}
            }
            
            
        ]
    },
```

Edited -
 Actually I want to maintain external playlist for songs list and need to connect with player. So how can I do it.

Comment: So... what's the question? What's actually going wrong that you would like help with? Or are you just sharing?

Comment: I m very sorry. Actually I want to maintain external playlist for songs list and need to connect with player. So how can I do it.

Comment: don't put extra question information in comments - update the question. Put more information into it and explain a) what you're trying to do and b) the problem you are having.